# Lisp Function That Count 1 2 occurrence in a List

Tags: lisp

The purpose of the function is to count the occurrence of 12 in a list using lisp.

**The code I wrote:**

```
(defun count12 (x)
    (if (null x) 0
        (if (and (= 1 (car x)) (= 2 (cadr x)))
            (+ 1 (count12 (cdr x)))
            (+ 0 (count12 (cdr x)))
         )
     )
)
```

**It produce error when I use it:**

> Error(s), warning(s):
>   *** - =: NIL is not a number

Note that I'm using Lisp online compiler: `rextester`.

Thank you for your help & guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you reach the last element of the list, you'll be comparing `2` and `nil` (the `cadr` of `nil` is `nil`).

You need to test for singleton lists:

```
(defun count12 (x)
    (if (or (null x) (null (cdr x))) 
        0
        (if (and (= 1 (car x)) (= 2 (cadr x)))
            (+ 1 (count12 (cdr x)))
            (+ 0 (count12 (cdr x))))))
```